# MySQL many tables or few tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I'm building a very large website currently it uses around 13 tables and by the time it's done it should be about 20.

I came up with an idea to change the preferences table to use ID, Key, Value instead of many columns however I have recently thought I could also store other data inside the table.

Would it be efficient / smart to store almost everything in one table?

**Edit:** Here is some more information. I am building a social network that may end up with thousands of users. MySQL cluster will be used when the site is launched for now I am testing using a development VPS however everything will be moved to a dedicated server before launch. I know barely anything about NDB so this should be fun :)

Comment: Use as many tables as you need, but no more/ use as few tables as you can but no less.

Comment: Short answer - no, it would be extremely BAD to store almost everything in 1 table.

Comment: Seriously, putting everything and the kitchensink in one table is a bad idea, read up on normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

This model is called `EAV` (entity-attribute-value)

It is usable for some scenarios, however, it's less efficient due to larger records, larger number or joins and impossibility to create composite indexes on multiple attributes.

Basically, it's used when entities have lots of attributes which are extremely sparse (rarely filled) and/or cannot be predicted at design time, like user tags, custom fields etc.

Comment: The main drawback of EAV is that you cannot enforce data domains easily (e.g., ensure that `autorized_ip_address` is a valid IP address, `percentage` is between 0 and 100 or `birthday` is a date). However, MySQL does not have check constrains anyway...

Comment: The main drawback of `EAV` is that is has about `3251` drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Granted I don't know too much about large database designs, but from what i've seen, even extremely large applications store their things is a very small amount of tables (20GB per table).

For me, i would rather have more info in 1 table as it means that data is not littered everywhere, and that I don't have to perform operations on multiple tables. Though 1 table also means messy (usually for me, each object would have it's on table, and an object is something you have in your application logic, like a User class, or a BlogPost class)

I guess what i'm trying to say is that do whatever makes sense. Don't put information on the same thing in 2 different table, and don't put information of 2 things in 1 table. Stick with 1 table only describes a certain object (this is very difficult to explain, but if you do object oriented, you should understand.)

Answer (score 0):

nope. preferences should be stored as-they-are (in users table)
for example private messages can't be stored in users table ...

you don't have to think about joining different tables ...

Comment: Should I store the profile/preferences in one table and then friends in another. Messages are already stored in a different table.

Comment: That is what I was thinking of, except for friends. There is also a second table for friend_requests. As for messages there's two tables one for posts and another for participants (as there can be multiple).

Comment: if your friends table has more than 100 000 rows, firends_requests should be in friends_requests, however you can put it into friends table and have status "accepted" -1 (not yet) 0 (ignored) 1 (accepted)

Comment: The site may have over a million users so I'm going to keep the 2-table system for friends. Right now it will make 2 rows for 1 friendship: 1 friends with 2, 2 friends with 1. Could this be changed? I tried making MySQL look on both columns only 1 row was required but this caused a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would first say that 20 tables is not a lot.

In general (it's hard to say from the limited info you give) the key-value model is not as efficient speed wise, though it can be more efficient space wise.

Comment: My app currently has... <runs a quick check> 169 tables, and will certainly have more. Granted, it's not a website but rather a CRM, but still 20 tables is not all that much.

Comment: The website is a social network. I am not sure how far it will go but we may end up with thousands of accounts. Although we will have MySQL cluster I don't know what to do for performance. I have never tackled a problem this large.

Comment: @user683812 Perhaps MySQL (or relational database in general) is not exactly what you need? Take a look into document databases like MongoDB for example.

Comment: What required tasks will give performance problems? If you can be specific, perhaps we can help.

Comment: Well currently MySQL pretty much handles everything including authentication. I chose not to use PHP's session manager because if a server fails the user can connect to another one. Just loading the home page is going to cause *at least* 100 SQL queries. I think that may be a lot when there are thousands of users interacting. Also there is heavy extensive use of AJAX, almost all of which will use several tables and many SQL queries. Just sitting on the homepage for 5 minutes racks up close to 500 queries.

Comment: I don't know the details of your system, but it sounds like there is some overkill there. One hundred queries to load the home page? but you only have 20 tables why would you need to query each more than once or twice?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely not do this. Basically, the reason being if you have a large set of data stored in a single table you will see performance issues pretty fast when constantly querying the same table. Then think about the joins and complexity of queries you're going to need (depending on your site)... not a task I would personally like to undertake.

With using multiple tables it splits the data into smaller sets and the resources required for the query are lower and as an extra bonus it's easier to program!

There are some applications for doing this but they are rare, more or less if you have a large table with a ton of columns and most aren't going to have a value.

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: So lots of tables? There's one large one for preferences, another large one for friends, another for profile information. All should stay separated right? Data is linked using PHP.

Comment: Use the tables you NEED, the best practice with databases generally speaking is to "group" similar sets of data, your tables may be user_info, messages, user_config, site_config, activity_log all of this data is grouped with other data that is similar in nature. You would use a JOIN in mySQL for example to get the right user_info with the messages data, you can then manipulate the data as you like with say PHP or JS. You will notice a table called activity_log, this is a good example of using an id, key and value as you could be logging 1,000 types of actions and don't need 1,001 fields

Comment: Sorry, to directly answer your question - yes, keep these separated :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think 20 tables in a project is not a lot. I do see your point and interest in using EAV but I don't think it's necessary. I would stick to tables in 3NF with proper FK relationships etc and you should be OK :)

Answer (score 0):

the simple answer is that 20 tables won't make it a big DB and MySQL won't need any optimization for that. So focus on clean DB structures and normalization instead.